# Masking of all digits but last four

Tags: regex

I have to mask value of feild in log file till the last four digits.The problem is length of digit is not fixed. It can be 16 digits or more.

For example

**ExtnTinNo="1234567891234567"**

Regex = **(ExtnTinNo=)(["'][^"']\d{12})**

It works fine , but when it is  more than 16 digits, unmasked digit will be more than 4.Also if there is a space b/w feild,= and value , it fails

Comment: What language/tool you're using for this masking?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to convert text like this:

```
ExtnTinNo="1234567891234567"
ExtnTinNo="12345678912345678912345"
```

to something like this:

```
ExtnTinNo="****4567"
ExtnTinNo="****2345"
```

If so, you should try the following Regex:

```
(?<=ExtnTinNo=['"])\d{12,}(?=[\d]{4}["'])
```

This will match all digits in your number, except for the last 4. That means, it will match the following:

```
ExtnTinNo="1234567891234567"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ExtnTinNo="12345678912345678912345"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By simply using Regex replacing, you will get the result given above.

It works this way:

```
(?<=ExtnTinNo=['"])  - checks that the number is preceded by ExtnTinNo="
                       (not included in the match)
\d{12,}              - matches 12 or more numbers
(?=[\d]{4}["'])      - if these 12 numbers are followed by another 4 numbers
                       and a " or ' (not included in the match)
```

Note that this does not cover your whitespace problem! Depending on your regex engine you can even add optional whitespace around the `=`. However, not all engines support look-behinds of variable length! For example, in .NET it should be possible to use this:

```
(?<=ExtnTinNo\s*=\s*['"])\d{12,}(?=[\d]{4}["'])
```

(see [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3C=ExtnTinNo%5Cs%2a=%5Cs%2a%5B%27%22%5D%29%5Cd%7B12,%7D%28?=%5B%5Cd%5D%7B4%7D%5B%22%27%5D%29&i=ExtnTinNo=%221234567891234567%22%0D%0AExtnTinNo=%2212345678912345678912345%22%0D%0AExtnTinNo%20=%20%20%221234567891234567%22%0D%0AExtnTinNo%09=%09%2212345678912345678912345%22&r=%2a%2a%2a%2a), click on "Context" tab to see the result after replacing)

Answer (score 2):

This should capture what you want:

```
(ExtnTinNo=)(["'][^"']*?)\d{4}["']
```

I'm not sure exactly what you should be capturing in the groups so I've left them as they were in your original regex. Group 1 matches 'EXtnTinNo=', group 2 matches the quotation mark followed by the numbers to mask.

**Breakdown:**

`(ExtnTinNo=)` matches ExtnTinNo= obviously

`\d{4}["']` matches the final 4 digits before the closing " or '

`(["'][^"']*?)` matches everything in between, i.e. ' or " followed by the numbers to mask

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=(ExtnTinNo=)(["'][^"']*?))\d{4}(?=["'])
```

Good Luck!