# Regex to mask a PhoneNumber

Tags: java, regex

I need to mask the phonenumber so that result is

```
 (***)-(***)-XXXX
```

XXXX being the last 4 digits of number.

Right now my code is

```
 String mask = phoneNumber.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^-()]*?.-)", "*");
```

Result is (***)***X-XXXX.

```
  String mask1 = phoneNumber.replaceAll("(?:[^()-])", "*");
```

Result is

```
 (***)-***-****
```

I am not able to know what mistake I am making.

Comment: Which language is this? Also, please show your input - the value of `phoneNumber`.

Comment: You can get an idea from this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000221/masking-of-all-digits-but-last-four

Comment: You would need to use the [**\G**](http://ideone.com/ZyYMuC) anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string =~ s{([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})}{($1)-($2)-$3}g;
```

Try this replace.